# StreamReader "detect encoding" Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, windows, io, stream

I'm just doing this:

```
using (var f = File.Open("File.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
      using (var sw = new StreamWriter(f, Encoding.ASCII))
      {
          sw.WriteLine("Test");
      }
}

using (var f = File.Open("File.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(f, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
      {
          var r = sr.ReadLine();
          var e = sr.CurrentEncoding;
          //e = UTF8Encoding ???????? !!!!!
      }
}
```

Why the stream does not detects correctly the encoding ?

Comment: Does the file you are reading have a byte order mark?

Comment: do you realize that automatic encoding detection is mostly a best-guess-based approach ...? you might want to have a look at UDE.

Comment: An ASCII file is also an UTF8 file, so probably you did everything right!

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN link on StreamReader.CurrentEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The value can be different after the first call to any Read method of StreamReader, since encoding autodetection is not done until the first call to a Read method.

Answer (score 0):

I found,

[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9y86s1a9(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter detects the encoding by
>   looking at the first three bytes of the stream.It automatically
>   recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text
>   if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks.Otherwise,
>   the UTF8Encoding is used.See the Encoding.GetPreamble method for more
>   information.

Comment: As noted in the comments, encoding detection (in the general case) is just a guess. If the file has byte order marks or other preamble bytes then the encoding might be detected, or you could've just tried to open a binary file which for some reason happen to have the right bytes at the start. In short, you're in a much better world if you write your code so that it uses only one known encoding and doesn't try to guess it.

Comment: Great @LasseV.Karlsen, tks so much.